# Azure auto scale decrease count by doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling, azure-app-service-plans

i've set up Azure auto scaling regarding some rules. Yesterday my website reached 65% memory usage , so new instance was added. But since yesterday night till now the memory usage is under 40% so i wondering why i still have 2 instances intead of 1 ( removing the 1 instance because of the rule memory < 40% decrease count by 1)

here are the screen capture

[Auto-scaling rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNcI3.png)

Even in the service management , only the rule increase count by 1 was reached as shown in the above capture

[Service management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amjQS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your rules might be overlapping, did you check if both the CPU and the Memory are under 40% ? to make sure they are not, You can try and remove the CPU rules to test. for testing purpose you can set the cool down to a low value 1-5mins.

I hope it helps,